# To get a Class object we use MyClass.class-It seems “class” is a static member of “MyClass”

Tags: java, class

To get a Class object we use MyClass.class-It seems “class” is a static member of “MyClass”

- Is “class” is static member of “MyClass” ?
- If so when is it added and who add this field ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the similar syntax, `class` is not a static member of each class. The expression `C.class` is called a *class literal* and is a special syntax that is understood by the compiler.

It's defined in the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> A *class literal* is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed by a `'.'` and the token `class`.